# Sort full join based on two columns on two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL database (Table A and Table B). Both of these tables have a createdAt column. I want to do a full join on these two tables and then sort the result based on createdAt values on both A and B tables. Below is an example of what I want to be my query result.

```
Table A
    colA  joinColumnA createdAtA
    ----- ----------- ---------
    a1    1           2014
    a2    2           2019
    a3    3           2020

Table B
   colB, joinColumnB createdAtB
   ---   ----------  -----------
   b1    2           2013
   b2    4           2015
   b3    5           2016


Result
    colA, joinColumnA createdAtA  colB  joinColumnB  createdAtB
    ----  ----------- ----------- ----  -----------  -----------
    a3    3           2020         null  null         null
    a2    2           2019         b1    2            2013
    null  null        null         b3    5            2016
    null  null        null         b2    4            2015
    a1    1           2014         null  null         null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `ORDER BY GREATEST(createdAtA, createdAtB)`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
FULL JOIN tableB
  ON tableA."joinColumnA" = tableB."joinColumnB"
ORDER BY GREATEST("createdAtA", "createdAtB") DESC;
```

| colA | joinColumnA | createdAtA | colB | joinColumnB | createdAtB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a3 | 3 | 2020 |  |  |  |
| a2 | 2 | 2019 | b1 | 2 | 2013 |
|  |  |  | b3 | 5 | 2016 |
|  |  |  | b2 | 4 | 2015 |
| a1 | 1 | 2014 |  |  |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the union for max createdAT for join column in left joinwitn the two table adn order by  ifnull(createdAtA, createdAtB)

```
    select colA, joinColumnA, createdAtA, null colB, null joinColumnB,  null createdAtB
    from (
        select joinColumn, max(createdAt)
        from (
            select joinColumnA joinColumn, createdAtA createdAt
            from tableA
            select joinColumnB , createdAtB
            from tableB
        ) t1
        group by joinColumn
    ) t2
    left join tableA ON tableA.joinColumnA = t2.joinColumn
    left join tableB ON tableB.joinColumnA = t2.joinColumn
    order by nullif(createdAtA, createdAtB)
```